# How to sort 10000 numbers between 1 and 50000

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I came across this interview question where the interviewer asked for how to sort 10000 numbers (present in an array) between 1 and 50k. It was followed up by to implement it in C++. All I know about sorting is the basic sorting algorithms which I assume the interviewer is not looking for.How can I do it?

Are there certain specific algorithms which take care of these type of conditions?

**UPDATE:** Sorry for bit of confusion,the 10000 numbers are not random but are present in an array and there value can be anything between 1 and 50k

**NOTE:** I am new to algorithms and C++ so I doubt that some of you might consider this question as being subjective as there is no code on my behalf but I would appreciate your help as I don't know about the algorithms that may help in this case.

Comment: What do you mean by between 1 and 50k?

Comment: [std::sort](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)?

Comment: If the numbers are unique then the range is small enough that you could have an array[50000] of bools that you set to all false and then set to true individually for each value you encounter as you iterate over the input. Finally iterate again and output all offset that are true. Might be faster than traditional sort methods.

Comment: This really isn't different from take these random 10,000 numbers that happen to be between 1 and 50,000 and sort them is it?

Comment: There are a lot of sorting algorithms, each one is good for some cases and bad for others, can you be more specific? did the interviewer add any additional details?

Comment: @JustinC: Well, it's O(n) instead of O(n log n).

Comment: @500-InternalServerError your boolean flag scheme will not work if there are duplicates. You want an integer count, not a flag.

Comment: What's the question here? You know the sorting algorithms, what else are you looking for? What's *your* answer?

Comment: If they're not random, they must be already in order.

Comment: @EJP The interview was not mine, so I don't know what was the answer.Like I said that I know the basic sorting algorithms but I do not know specialised sorting algos and I guess the interviewer was looking for specialised one only

Comment: Maybe the interviewer is seeing if you are indeed a C++ programmer (and not a C programmer masquerading as a C++ programmer).  The answer could be just "use std::sort".

Comment: I didn't ask what *the* answer was. I asked what *your* answer is. And why, come to think of it. We need somewhere to start from.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I doubt that as the first question was to tell how will you sort and then subsequent question was to implement it in C++.If he was checking for programming skill only he would have directly asked to implement

Comment: @EJP that's what I am saying that as a rookie I am unaware of specialised sorting algos.If this question would have been asked to me my answer would have been any standard sorting algo like bubble sort or insertion sort

Comment: @user2916886 Why? On what basis? Why not quicksort for example? What considerations do you think would be relevant?

Answer (score 4):

You could allocate 50,000 bytes, initialize them to 0. Then use this array to count how many times each value occurs in the source array in one pass. You can then make a pass over the size 50,000 array and extract the values.

This is commonly known as [Pigeonhole Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_sort).

Comment: @KenWhite they would be sorted in the array...

Comment: @KenWhite: once you have that array, you can sort easily

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi no, this is a bucket sort.

Comment: @Mhd. Tahawi, no this is different than radix sort. You don't go a place value at a time. You count how many times each value occurs. You trade memory for speed. You can do this because the limited range of the values you are sorting makes the memory cost relatively small.

Comment: Thanks, I meant bucket sort, but I mixed them up. 
I guess it is worth it to mention the name of the technique in the answer.
thanks again for the correction

Comment: @Apriori  so the bucket sort caters to sort small number of values in a large range of values?

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi, NP, I can add that. The term "Bucket Sort" actually wasn't going through my head when I answered this. I just reasoned through it. But I do recall that term now that its mentioned.

Comment: @Apriori: Yes, I misread your answer. When I re-read it and saw what you actually wrote, I deleted my comment. :-)

Comment: @user2916886, Actually that's backwards. Bucket Sort is good for a large number of values in a small range. A "normal" sort algo will be O(n*log(n)) where n is the number of values being sorted. This algorithm is O(max(n,m)) where m is the range of values, aka the size of the second array. So the more saturated this second array becomes, the greater the perf advantage over a normal sort. But of course you'd want to measure it in a real world scenario. Details like cache size will come into play.

Comment: @Mhd.Tahawi, Just looked it up. It's actually a special case of Bucket Sort known as Pigeonhole Sort.

Comment: Correcting myself - Actually, this is O(n + m) not O(max(n, m))

Comment: And if the array contained more than 255 of any particular number, you'd be in trouble. If the numbers are in the range 1..50000, each of your buckets must be able to store that range. You'll need an array of 16-bit integers, not bytes.

Comment: @JimMischel, yes that's absolutely correct for the first part, a bucket can't hold more than 255 in this scene. However I disagree on the second part, your bucket doesn't have to be sized to handle a range of 1 to 5000, rather you merely need more buckets for bigger ranges. Also, you could establish an upper bound based on the input size and pick a perhaps templatized version of the algo (templatized with byte/short/int ect). Or one could detect the rollover and allocate a second array for the high bits. However some of the big-oh starts to change.